# Table alignment with div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to construct an html table with 6 rows. The first row has one line of text which is heading. The second row has 3 columns (set as three td elements). Third row has three values in 3 columns (set as three td elements). 4th row has 3 images in 3 columns (again set as three td elements). This works correctly so far. Now I want to add a fifth row which is a line of text that spans the entire div and has a dotted underline. When I add this element it just draws the the dotted border to 1/3rd of the div only. If I set the width to 100%, the elements above it are dragged to the right of the screen. What am I doing wrong? Here is my complete HTML snippet:

```
 <div id="ToySummary" style="border:solid; border-width:4px; border-color:gray; padding:4px; margin:10px">
   <span style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:large; color:midnightblue; text-align:right"><b>FINAL RESULTS SUMMARY</b></span>
   <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
          <td style="width:33%; font-size:large"><i>Result</i></td>
          <td style="width:33%; font-size:large"><i>Lucky Toy</i></td>
          <td style="width:33%; font-size:large"><i>Lucky Peoples</i> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:33%; font-size:large">{{overall_result}}</td>
        <td style="width:33%; font-size:large">{{lucky}}</td>
        <td style="width:33%; font-size:large">{{lucky_peoples}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
          <td><img src={{some_png}} style="width:50px;height:50px;"></td>
        <td><img src={{some_other_png}} style="width:50px;height:50px;"></td>
        <td><img src={{another_png}} style="width:50px;height:50px;"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style=" border-bottom-style:dotted; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-width: 2px;"><b><em>{{animal_test_note}}</em></b></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>{{toy_score_note}}</td>
      </tr>

  </table>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make the last two tr's span all the columns? Try this

```
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style=" border-bottom-style:dotted; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-width: 2px;"><b><em>{{animal_test_note}}</em></b></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td colspan="3">{{toy_score_note}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's so awesome. What is the meaning of colspan="3"?

Comment: It's however many columns (td) the given td should span. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use colspan attribute inside  to span ur dotted border across all columns.

***{{animal_test_note}}***

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you right, you try to align a dotted bottom border to your fifth `td` cell? And every try goes wrong and does not cover the whole bottom line?

I would recommend using CSS classes and ids instead of writing the style part directly into the `td` tags.
It's messy coding! No offense!

And for your approach:

HTML part:

```
<td id="dotted">
```

CSS part:

```css
#dotted {
    border-bottom: dotted #000000; /* or any colour you prefer! */
    width:100%;
}
```

By the way: using `%` and then `px` in your `td` tags could cause your problem stick to one.

that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td colspan="3" style=" border-bottom-style:dotted; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-width: 2px;"><b><em>{{animal_test_note}}</em></b></td>
```

this will fix it.